# Twitter or normal account username conflict - Meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

The user can create an account with their e-mail or twitter. The problem with the code below is, it doesn't let the user with normal account create a post.

```
Posts.insert({
      text: text,
      createdAt: new Date(),
      owner: Meteor.userId(),
      username: Meteor.user().username,
      twitname: Meteor.user().profile.name,
      upvoters: [],
      votes: 0,
      commenters: [],
      comments: 0,    
});
```

If I erase

```
      twitname: Meteor.user().profile.name,
```

both of the accounts can create posts again but it doesn't show the username for the posts created by a twitter account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to this. Hope this helps someone.

What we do is telling "username" to get data from one or another like below.

Inside server, Meteor.methods:

```
username: function(){
   return Meteor.user().username || Meteor.user().profile.name
}
```

And our insert method:

```
Posts.insert({
    text: text,
    createdAt: new Date(),
    owner: this.userId,
    username: Meteor.user().username,
});
```

Inside HTML:

```
{{username}}
```

PS: I have installed Sign in with Google, Twitter and FB. The solution above works with all of them.

**EDIT:**

I found out that its better to use onCreateUser

Example:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options,user){
    if (typeof(user.services.facebook) != "undefined") {
        username: user.services.facebook.name;
    }

    if (typeof(user.services.google) != "undefined") {
        user.username = user.services.google.name;
    }

    //etc.
})
```

This way, you don't have to check which service and write anything else as its always "username" for all services. You just insert the correct data to the same place.